# Parallel processing: @everywhere, distributions and types

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I have recently started studying parallel processing in Julia and I am having an issue which I don't really understand how to fix.

After having executed Julia with `julia -p 4` I want to load the Distributions module in all the processes and I would like to define a Type which depends on Distributions.

The following apparently works correctly when I include it:

```
 @everywhere using Distributions

 type TypeDistrib{T <: Float64}
      d::Distributions.Normal{T}
 end
```

If I write exactly the same code as a module, then it doesn't:

```
 module test

    @everywhere using Distributions

    type TypeDistrib{T <: Float64}
         d::Distributions.Normal{T}
    end

    export TypeDistrib
 end
```

The above gives the following error message:

> ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: Distributions not defined
>    in include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:488
>    in include_from_node1(::String) at /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
>   while loading /***/test.jl, in expression starting on line 4

Would you please clarify what I am not doing correctly here?

Note: I replaced the full path in the error message with *** since it was confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@everywhere something` evaluates `something` in the Main module across all processes. And in this case, not in `test` module, and therefore the error in the second case and not in the first.

Perhaps

```
@everywhere module test
    using Distributions

    type TypeDistrib{T <: Float64}
        d::Distributions.Normal{T}
    end

    export TypeDistrib
end
```

does what is meant.

Comment: This is probably what it should be. However, it is not super clear why exactly the code I wrote doesn't work. Could you please clarify a bit more your point?

Comment: `using Distributions` is evaluated as if written in Main module, and `Distributions.Normal{T}` is searched in `test` module (where it is defined) and so it's not found. For example, using `Main.Distributions.Normal{T}` works in `test` as defined in the question.