# @everywhere and relative path

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

Working following the direction suggested after a recent question of mine ([Parallel processing: @everywhere, distributions and types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547850/parallel-processing-everywhere-distributions-and-types)) I tried to set up a module using @everywhere, with a type depending on a package.

However, this arises a different question - as suggested in meta I created a new post. Let's say I have the following module (in test.jl):

```
@everywhere module test
    using Distributions

    type TypeDistrib{T <: Float64}
        d::Distributions.Normal{T}
    end

    include('./folder1/fun1.jl');
    export TypeDistrib, fun1
end
```

where fun1 is a function (in fun1.jl) and a simple script (in script.jl):

```
include("./testdir/test.jl");
using test
```

In addition, let's assume that these file are stored as follows:

```
-> example/
   -  script.jl
   -> testdir/
      -  test.jl
      -> folder1/
         -  fun1.jl
```

When I run it using *example* as my working dir without @everywhere, then it works with no errors. If I run it with @everywhere it says that the file fun1.jl doesn't exist.

I noticed that when I use @everywhere the relative path is linked with my working dir and not with the directory in which the module is stored. Am I missing something? Could you please clarify how I should set correctly the relative path using @everywhere - or more generally in case my settings are not accurate?

Comment: using dirname( [@__FILE__](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/file.html#Base.@__FILE__) ) is more robust when working with relative paths.

Comment: @Gnimuc I googled @__FILE__ and I have found an open issue on it (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17500) so I don't think that it would work. The workaround in this link is a bit difficult to apply on my example, since I have a module.